# How can I display images that are saved in state?

Tags: reactjs, image, heroku

I am trying to make a simple image gallery using Heroku's new simple-file-upload, and have managed to save images to the database but am having trouble displaying them on the site. I created a "displayImage" function, which I would like to render the images I've uploaded. But it's not seeming to work. I don't get any errors, and am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleFileUpload, { SimpleFileUploadProvider } from "../components/SimpleFileUpload"
import { useState } from 'react'

const API_KEY = '...'


export default function About() {

  const [file, setFile] = useState()

  const displayImage = (file) => {

    return file.map((file, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="file-display">
        <img>class="gallery" src={file} alt="no"</img>
      </div>
    ))
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>upload an image</h1>
      <SimpleFileUpload apiKey={API_KEY} onSuccess={setFile} />
      {file && <p> Uploaded: {file}</p>}

      {file && <div className="gallery">
        {displayImage(file)}
</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I made some tweaks with the help of another user on here, and it seems to be working... just nothing is rendering on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: is this typo ? `<img>class="gallery" src={file} alt="no"</img>`

Comment: btw what you mean save an image file? u just need a URL!

Comment: @b3hr4d No, it's not. I'm guessing it's wrongly placed?

Comment: it should be like this : `<img class="gallery" src={file} alt="no"/>` can you share your console log from API ?

Answer (score 1):

If your `files` is an array of URLs it should be like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
...

export default function About() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>upload an image</h1>
      <SimpleFileUpload apiKey={API_KEY} onSuccess={setFile} />
      {files && (
        <div>
          <p> Uploaded: {files.length}</p>
          <div className="gallery">
            <DisplayImages images={files} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const DisplayImages = ({ images }) =>
  images.map((image, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="file-display">
      <img class="gallery" src={image} alt="no" />
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm pretty sure the files are URLs. I get this error when I try to use your code however: TypeError: images.map is not a function

Comment: Can you share your console log from `files`?

Comment: When I console.log(files) I get this in return: https://static.files-simplefileupload.com/sdx0pmx2gxq6b40aezw15y18vdla/SampleJPGImage_500kbmb.jpg

Comment: its just 1 url not array of url. if you want gallery you should pass url inside an array like this `["url.to.your.img","another.url.to.your.img"]`

Comment: If you want show an image just remove `map` inside `DisplayImages`: `const DisplayImages = ({ images }) => (
    <div className="file-display">
      <img class="gallery" src={images} alt="no" />
    </div>
  )`